# How do I save a complete InkCanvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I am trying to save a drawing from InkCanvas. I also implemented zoom capabilities and scrollbars to increase the size of the InkCanvas. The picture that is saved depends on the zoom, and, even when the size is the original, it does not save the complete InkCanvas.

XAML for InkCanvas:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Border x:Name="brd_borger"  MouseWheel="cnv_MouseWheel" Background="Aqua" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
        <InkCanvas x:Name="cnv" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="Aqua" 
               PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="cnv_MouseLeftButtonDown"
               PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="cnv_MouseRightButtonDown" 
               SelectionChanged="cnv_SelectionChanged"
               SelectionMoving="cnv_SelectionMoving"
               SelectionMoved="cnv_SelectionMoved"

               EditingMode="None">

        </InkCanvas>
    </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Zooming Code:

```
private void cnv_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
        {
            var matrix = cnv.LayoutTransform.Value;

            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                matrix.ScaleAt(1.5, 1.5, e.GetPosition(this).X, e.GetPosition(this).Y);
            }
            else
            {
                matrix.ScaleAt(1.0/1.5, 1.0/1.5, e.GetPosition(this).X, e.GetPosition(this).Y);
            }

            cnv.LayoutTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);

        }
    }
```

Saving Code:

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".png";
        dlg.Filter = ODLG_FILTER_IMAGES;

        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);

            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)cnv.Width, (int)cnv.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
            rtb.Render(cnv);
            BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

            encoder.Save(fs);
            fs.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the target size of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want the size of the image to be the same as the actual size of the `InkCanvas`, you need to specify the actual target image size somwhere. You could then use a `DrawingContext` and a `VisualBrush` to create the image:

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".png";
    dlg.Filter = ODLG_FILTER_IMAGES;

    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        string filename = dlg.FileName;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);

        //define your image size here...
        const int Width = 200;
        const int Height = 200;
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(Width, Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
        Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(cnv);
        DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext ctx = dv.RenderOpen())
        {
            VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(cnv);
            ctx.DrawRectangle(vb, null, new Rect(new Point(), bounds.Size));
        }

        rtb.Render(dv); ;
        BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

        encoder.Save(fs);
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @TheBosco: Did you try this?